# Does meteor autoload the css files

Tags: meteor

I found that I don't need to write css links in the head.But the css still works.If so,then how do I manage my css file.For example, use different css file in different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A the moment, you have something like this:

```html
<template name="myTemplateName">
    <p>HTML!</p>
</template>
```

```css
/* Should only affect paragraphs in the template above. */
p{
    color: red;
}
```

You must change that to something like this:

```html
<template name="myTemplateName">
    <div class="myTemplateName">
        <p>HTML!</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

```css
/* Will only affect paragraphs in the "template" above. */
.myTemplateName p{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css files named like template and meteor will include it

Comment: Can you write a example?Still confused.

Comment: Best way to manage those files is to name .html and .css as template name, so if you got template named "example", then you should create "example.html" and "example.css". However, Meteor will merge all those css files into one, so you should use individual classes for every template if you want to keep this apart

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is for [SPA - Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) .In SPA, all your Css files will be complied and minified into a single file and served to the client in the initial page load. It is same with Html and Javascript file. In meteor it is one of the seven core principle ([Data on the wire](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/sevenprinciples)). The only things that goes between your client and server after the initial page load is your data, not the HTML or Css content.

Meteor team working on a mechanism to control the file load order. Check the [trello](https://trello.com/c/mHK2dpr5/68-new-way-of-defining-packages-and-controlling-file-load-order) board for information.